# Excel VBA: Merging rows from 2 different files with for each loops

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 different Excel files. I created a third `.xls` file, where I will write the macro. That macro needs to check the data from the first `.xls` file for all records, and each record should be compared to the records in the other `.xls` file, and if they match; I should copy the whole records from the original `.xls` file to the new `.xls` file, and add a new cell to that record with information.

This should look something like that in VBA:

```
SrcFile1 = path
SrcFile2 = path

for each record in src file1.sheet1
   temp valuecell=record.cell(B1)
   for each recordToCompare in srcfile2.sheet1
      temp valuecell2=recordToCompare.cell(B1)
      if(valuecell1==valuecell2) then
         ThisWorkbook.thisworksheet.activate
         valuecell2.copy
         add new cell = value valuecell1.range(A1)
   end for each
end for each
```

If anyone could give me a hint or just a bit of help, I would really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, change it to how you want it:

```
SrcFile1 = "path"
SrcFile2 = "path2"

dim i as long
dim wkb1 as workbook, wkb2 as workbook
dim wks1 as worksheet, wks2 as worksheet
dim v1 as variant, v2 as variant

'Get workbooks
set wkb1=getobject(srcfile1)
set wkb2=getobject(srcfile2)
'Get worksheets
set wks1=wkb1.worksheets("Sheet1")
set wks2=wkb2.worksheets("Sheet1")
'Get data - transpose single column data so array will be one dimensional
v1=application.transpose(wks1.range("A1:A" & wks1.range("A65000").end(xlup).row))
v2=application.transpose(wks2.range("A1:A" & ubound(v1)))

for i=1 to ubound(v1)
  if v1(i)<> v2(i) then
    'Copy over different data, don't know how many columns you have, 
    ' you can also do a .end(xlleft) to get the last column
    wks2.range("A" & i & ":Q" & i)=wks1.range("A" & i & ":Q" & i)
    wks2.range("R" & i)= "Information here"
  end if
next i
```

A path you can make as the following: "C:\ExcelFileName.xls"
If you are comparing multiple columns then you will need two loops, I thought you were only doing one to one. So you would need to do something like this (I'll let you work out the correct logic for your application):

```
dim j as long

v1=wks1.range(cells(1,1), cells(wks1.range("A65000").end(xlup).row _
   , wks.range("IV1").end(xlLeft))
v2=wks2.range(cells(1,1),cells(ubound(v1),ubound(v1,2))

for i=1 to ubound(v1)
  for j=1 to ubound(v1,2)
    if v1(i,j)<> v2(i,j) then
      wks2.range(cells(i,1),cells(i,ubound(v1,2))) _
           =wks1.range(cells(i,1),cells(i,ubound(v1,2)))
      wks2.range(cells(i,ubound(v1,2)+1))= "Information here"
      exit for
```

Comment: Ok directly few questions to about it:

Comment: How exactly do i make paths in which format? 
What you wrote in transpose i dont really understand, you say A1 and then you kinda make a string, but will it not lose the structure like let say if it is 10 columns, will it be after that all info in 1 column? because in one row i just need to check one cell and compare it and then i just need to copy whole row, without changing anything but only at the end of that row in a new xls i need to add a new cell with some extra info. 
You still need 2 nested loops to make it work.

Comment: Could you also tell what does "wks1.range("A65000").end(xlup).row" exactly means? Emphasising A65000

Comment: Sorry, I was being lazy, for excel 2003 there are just over 65000 rows so what you do is point to the very last row then go up, it is very fast (excel doesn't really start at the last row, it starts in the used range internally). So a better way of doing it would be Application.Rows.Count to get the last row, then it will tell you the last filled row on whatever column you are using.

Comment: Where exactly should i put Application.Rows.Count , sorry for such a stupid questions but im kinda bad at vba ... or really bad. But i still dont uderstnad why you dont use for each, like for each row in sheet then you copy that row and paste it in other document with extra cell, but now you say soemthing with bound, and the if is hard to understand you say if they arent the same? but i need to find the one cell should be same as the other cell in other xls document and only then copy it.

Comment: Put Application.Rows.Count where "A65000" is like '"A" & Application.Rows.Count' and Application.Columns.Count where "IV1" is like 'Cells(1,Application.Columns.Count).Address'. Sorry, I'm giving you an efficient way to do it, I thought it would be more easy to understand too, using for each (looping through each range) is extremely slow, that's why I don't use it. If this is too complicated for you you can try something else.